# ALB and ECS Fargate Issue - Causing 502 Error

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have configured ALB and registered ecs fargate containers as target.

After deployment, containers are running as expected. But sometimes, ALB registers the target as unhealthy and it kills the existing container and starts a new container. During this restart, production users are getting affected and they are getting "502 - Bad gateway error".

1. Health check path for the ALB Target group is '/'. How health check is passing most of the time and it is failing sometimes?
2. I checked the CPU Utilization of ECS, which is average. Hence, configuration of fargate container may not be the issue causing health check failure.

Please provide your input on this issue.

Comment: If it is failing the health check then _something_ is causing it to stop returning a `200` response at the `/` path for some period of time. For example, perhaps the application is crashing inside the container, or perhaps it has a memory leak that is causing it to hang once it runs out of RAM. You need to be looking at the container logs, and all metrics (not just CPU) to research the issue.